# When I open Scilab through Dash, it's closed immediately after the program opened

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop, scilab

I have installed Scilab manually, copied the Scilab.desktop to the directory `/user/share/applications`.

When I open Scilab using the Scilab command, it works well.But when I open Scilab through Dash, Scilab is opened, then closed immediately.

Can someone explain this and help me fix the issue?

Comment: How do you start Scilab from a terminal? What's the content of `/user/share/applications/Scilab.desktop`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I make a symbolic link to the file bin/scilab, and type the command scilab. You can download the latest Scilab package from the official site and extract it, search the file scilab.desktop and open it with an editor.

Comment: Which *exact* command did you run to create the symbolic link and, if relative paths were involved, in which working directory? Which package *exactly* did you download and extract/install? There are multiple and it would be easier if you just provided the content of that particular file.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The package I downloaded is of course 64 bit, and the symbolic is absolute path. I have installed Scilab before using apt and removed it. I am very sorry that it's inconvenient to visit this site because the site is blocked partially in China.

Comment: Again: What *exactly* did you do to create the symbolic link? Please **[edit]** your question when you want to clarify something or add new info. Why do I need to download and extract a 200 MB archive when you can just upload that one file of less than 1 KB? Do you think it's a good idea to put hurdles into the way of the people who try to *help you **for free***?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have found that GNU Octave has the same problem, Ubuntu's solution is to add the --force-gui option to the command octave. But Scilab has no similar option. I think the problem is too difficult for me.I want to upload the desktop file, but I can't sign up via a browser because this site is partially blocked in China.In addition, I don't think the issue is caused by the file, it is probably caused by Java version or GUI incompatibility. Thank you very much.